# minimum number of pixel points for regression on atmospherically corrected satellite images

Tags: modis, landsat-8, correlation, atmospheric-correction

I am performing atmospheric correction on a Landsat 8 image using different methods to check which one works best (in order to proceed with further/subsequent analysis). Wondering if it's okay to use as low as 5 observations (pixel points) for regression analysis (to check for agreement between Landsat, dependent variable and MODIS Surface Reflectance, independent variable).

Comment: Statistics says 10 in case of one independent variable